# www.example.tk don't work but example.tk work

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a big problem with my Domain.

When i type www.example.tk in my browser it does not work. But when i'm using 
example.tk it works.
Im hosting on a NAT VPN with ivp6 and cloudfare. 
CentOS6 and httpd

It says DNS adress not found for this adress

Comment: 1) Make sure both domains resolve to your IP (`nslookup`). 2) Make sure your virtual host configuration is correct (`httpd.conf` or related files). It might be easier if you actually posted what your virtual host configuration is.

Comment: IP address or host name:     
Using domain server:
Name:
 127.0.0.1

Address:
 127.0.0.1#53
Aliases:

example.tk has address 104.31.74.172
example.tk has address 104.31.75.172
example.tk has IPv6 address 2400:cb00:2048:1::681f:4aac
example.tk has IPv6 address 2400:cb00:2048:1::681f:4bac

Comment: FOR www.example.tk

Comment: Using domain server:
Name:
 127.0.0.1

Address:
127.0.0.1#53
Aliases:

Comment: You might not want to post those, if you went to trouble to anonymise with `example.tk`. I just meant, check that public-facing IP (not 127.0.0.1) of both `www.example.tk` and `example.tk` is the same; and post the (anonymised) excerpt from Apache conf regarding `VirtualHost`...`ServerName`.

Comment: Config: http://pastebin.com/UFyZs2Mb     it does make no sense to me why www don't work :(

Comment: You don't seem to have any virtual hosts defined; if both names resolve to the same IP, no idea either.